# Can't get angular-fullstack generator to compile

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp, angular-fullstack

I'm currently trying to start a project using the angular-fullstack generator (https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack) but I keep running into errors trying to set up the project.

I'm running this on Mac OSX with node v7.7.3 and npm v4.4.1

This is the error i get after i run "yo angular-fullstack"

```
> iltorb@1.0.13 install /Users/USER/Desktop/forecast-me/node_modules/iltorb
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config -c import platform; print(platform.python_version());
gyp ERR! stack Usage: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config [--prefix|--exec-prefix|--includes|--libs|--cflags|--ldflags|--help]
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:210:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:899:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:342:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:513:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 15.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/USER/Desktop/forecast-me/node_modules/iltorb
gyp ERR! node -v v7.7.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.5.0
gyp ERR! not ok 

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! iltorb@1.0.13 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the iltorb@1.0.13 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the iltorb package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs iltorb
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls iltorb
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

And then if i follow up and run "gulp serve":

```
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'shrink-ray'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/USER/Desktop/forecast-me/server/config/express.js:10:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at loader (/Users/USER/Desktop/forecast-me/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/USER/Desktop/forecast-me/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/USER/Desktop/forecast-me/server/app.js:24:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at loader (/Users/USER/Desktop/forecast-me/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/USER/Desktop/forecast-me/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Answer (score 0):

Express server uses the **shrink-ray** module to compress assets before sending them over http. Nevertheless, **shrink-ray** depends on the **node-zopfli** module to install properly.

In order for **node-zopfli** to install properly, npm tries to download a compatible prebuilt binary. In the case of failure npm falls back to building that binary. A problem occurs occasionally when node-gyp is unable to build node-zopfli.

So, here are some paths you may explore:

1. Try installing a c++ compiler like g++ on linux
2. Remove the **shrink-ray** dependancy from package.json and the reference to shrink-ray in the **server/config/express.js** file